# Ошибка при попытке скомпилировать .java-файл

Tags: java, компиляция

При попытке скомпилировать через javac в cmd выдает следующее сообщение: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать, чтобы файл был скомпилирован (не через IDE)?

Comment: Видать вам надо javaOptions выставить меньше. Ну или операты добавить

Comment: А в чём проблема с компиляцией файла без задания ограничений? По поводу самих ограничений: попробуйте `-J-Xms` и `-J-Xmx` вместо `Xms` и `Xmx`.

Comment: @Regent, немного не точно заскринил место в консоли. Пробовал и без Xms и прочего, но разницы нету.

Comment: А что насчет ключей вида `-J-Xms`, на которые я наткнулся на enSO?

Comment: @Regent, поздновато прочитал. Нет, то же и самое